# Auto-naming temporary layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, rename

I get a lot of temporary layers called 'Union' or 'Singlepart'. And then I lose myself in which layer is which in when for example I want to check geometry.

Can I do so that QGIS is naming them 'Union1', 'Union2' automatically like in ArcView 3.2?

Comment: Afaik this is not currently possible, but would indeed be very nice to have. As of now, you can only either set a file-path/-name to save the processing output to a file (but than it's not a temporary layer anymore) or change the name of the temporary output manually. In both cases, it's not automatically. See also here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29716

Comment: Possible workaround could be to write a python-script that re-names temporary output layers - for this, I would suggest to ask another question here precisely for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can always change the names of the layers. Right click over layer > Rename. This is also added as issue for QGIS development: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29716

Comment: I think the point of the question was to automatically change the name, not manually.

Comment: @Sanna good to point out that there has been a request in the past for that feature. Would be nice to see if it will be added at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, processes you use generate a lot of temp layers which misleading names. Most of the tools in QGIS are usable also through Graphic Process Modeler where you can name any output there.
In this case my temp layer will be named joinedbefunds.

[image]